# Foundation Magellan re-init

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, scrollspy

How do I re-init the Foundation Magellan plugin? I need to do that, because the magellan is located inside a tab, and I need to re-init 'magellan-top-offset' once the tab has been opened.

`$(document).foundation('magellan', 'init');` doesn't do the trick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so the problem was stupid as ever, actually the full module's name is `magellan-expedition`, not `magellan`.

So the correct code that does the trick is this:

```
$(document).foundation('magellan-expedition','set_expedition_position');
```

Comment: Do you know how to for f6?